# Service Stack Redis in Web Api OData add EdmEntityObject / EdmEntityObjectCollection

Tags: dynamic, asp.net-web-api, redis, servicestack, odata

We are able to add a normal POCO class to a Service Stack Redis client

```
IRedisTypedClient<Product> objRedisTypedClientNB = redisClient.As<Product>();
IRedisList<Product> objRedisListNB = objRedisTypedClientNB.Lists["Product"];
Product objNews = new Product(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
objRedisTypedClientNB.Lists["Product"].Push(objNews);
```

Adding products object to redis cache is fine

When using dynamic web api odata v4 service, 
Metadata is created at runtime for each request based on url

How to add EdmEntityObject / EdmEntityObjectCollection into redis

```
EdmEntityObject objEntityObject = new EdmEntityObject((EdmEntityType)objEntityType);
objEntityObject.TrySetPropertyValue("Id", "test id");

IRedisTypedClient<EdmEntityObject> objRedisTypedClientEEOC = redisClient.As<EdmEntityObject>();
IRedisList<EdmEntityObject> objRedisListEEOC = objRedisTypedClientEEOC.Lists["EntityName"];

objRedisTypedClientEEOC.Lists["EntityName"].Add(objEntityObject); // throws error
```

Error
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Unknown Module.

1. How to resolve the error
2. How to add EdmEntityObject / EdmEntityObjectCollection 's instances into redis cache

Note:
1. Should not use POCO classes
2. ODataModel itself is created at runtime only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `System.StackOverflowException` is indicative that you're trying to serialize non-serializable objects with cyclical dependencies which are not supported in any of ServiceStack's Serializers (and will also fail in most other Serializers).

Essentially EF DataModels have cyclical dependencies making them poor candidates for serialization. You should instead have them map to clean DTO's which can be serialized, or alternatively use any Micro ORM like [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) or [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) which map resultsets into clean POCO models.

As a goal [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) ensures that all its features (inc. its [Reference Support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#reference-conventions)) maps to clean disconnected POCO's so they're always serializable and can be re-used in Services DTO's and other NoSQL datastores.

Comment: In our case, these DTO classes are not available.
Properties / Metadata is generated for each and every request at runtime using **ODataModelBuilder**.

1. Is it possible to add DataTable, DataRow / DataSet to redis cache? 
   `DataTable dtb = new DataTable();
    RedisClient redisClient = new RedisClient(host);
    redisClient.Set("key", dtb);`
This also throws **StackOverflowException.**
2. How to store these kind of objects in redis cache? 
3. Manually serialize these objects to JSON / XML string and store in redis cache? Is this the best approach?

Comment: @Navaneeth DataTable's aren't serializable for the same reasons. If you know of a serializer that supports them you can serialize them into a string and cache the serialized string with `SetEntry/GetEntry` API's.